# Can somebody explain this nested loop?

Tags: java, loops, nested

I have the solution to the code, but I don't understand how it works. Can somebody explain?

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
      for (int j = i; j <= 4; j++)
          System.out.print(j + " ");
```

The output for the code is 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 3 4

Comment: Have you tried to run the code "on paper"?

Comment: What do you mean by "on paper"?

Comment: Do dry run first using pen paper.

Comment: Can't explain how it works, because it doesn't. Compile error in line 1.

Comment: Yeah I didn't include the bracket. I assumed you'd put it there yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j` starts at `i=1` and goes to 4.

`i` increments.

`j` starts at `i=2` and goes to 4.

Rinse, repeat...

Maybe this visual helps delineate the loops

```
1 2 3 4 | 2 3 4 | 3 4
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer here. Thanks.

Comment: It was the "first" answer here :)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning I is at 1 so j goes to 1 to 4 right

Than I pass to 2 so j goes to 2 to 4 cuz I=j remember

Than I pass to 3 so j goes to 3 to 4 and voila

You get: 1234 234 34...

Comment: While you are correct, you didn't provide any additional information to the existing answer